# Plotting 3D with parameter

Tags: plotting

Can someone help in plotting this graph? K is a parameter. Thanks

```
1 + 1/(4*k^2 + (2*k*Sqrt[t])/Abs[y] e^(-(y^2/(4*k*t))) + 
  Sqrt[k*Pi]*Erf[Abs[y]/(2*Sqrt[k*t])])
```

Comment: Note that the basis of natural logarithms should be uppercase `E` in *Mathematica*, not `e`.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `Plot`? Probably you can make a `Table` (look it up in the documentation) of these functions, one for each `k`, and then `Plot` them.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks, the 'e' was the problem.

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.
Why not choosing a meaningful username?

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e it arises from a simple mistake (syntax error, incorrect capitalization, spelling mistake) and is unlikely to help any future visitors, or else it is easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397).

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[
  (4 k^2 + (2 E^(-(y^2/(4 k t))) k Sqrt[t])/Abs[y] + 
    Sqrt[k] Sqrt[π] Erf[Abs[y]/(2 Sqrt[k t])])^-1
  , {t, -8, 8}
  , {y, -8, 8}
  , PlotRange -> Full
  ], {k, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]